# If I turn on FileVault for a TimeMachine drive, are previous backups encrypted

Tags: time-machine, filevault

I have been running TimeMachine for a couple of months, but just now decided to encrypt my backups.  Having ticked the box for encryption for my backup drive, TimeMachine nows says I have no previous backups.  However, when I look in the backup drive I can see all the backup folders.

Are those backups encrypted, or is it just future ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FileVault itself does not encrypt TimeMachine backups at all. But you can specify TimeMachine encryption separately under the TimeMachine options. All contents on the disk should be encrypted then.

[image]